# how to open a textfield and set its value on select some value in dropdown in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display a textbox based on some selected value in dropdown in react.
my code is

```
<label>
 color:
<select value="Radish" onChange ={this.checkColor}>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Radish">Radish</option>
<option value="Cherry">Cherry</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="project Id" id="project Id" style={{display:'none'}}/>
<label>
```

Onchange, the below function will be invoked.

```
CheckLayers(evt){
if(evt.target.value === 'Orange'){
   this.setState({showField:true})
  }
 }
```

But I am not able to see the textbox. I tried to put condition based on showField but that's not working.

```
     (this.state.showField)
      <input type="text" name="project Id" id="project Id" style={{display:'none'}}/>
```

Please advice!!

Comment: 1. Your onChange is referring to this.checkColor but your function is called CheckLayers
2. if the state showField state is changing to true when u select orange, then wrap the input field in a conditionally like this

    { this.state.showField && <input type="text" name="project Id" id="project Id" style={{display:'none'}}/>}

Comment: Thanks a lot.. And it was typo. Sorry for that

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things to check in your code.

First, with your current implementation of the `<select>` and `<option>` elements, the actual value on the `<select>` will never change because it is always set to `"Orange"`. You need to also save the last selected `<select>` value in your component's state:

```js
checkLayers(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      showField: value === "Orange",
      selectedValue: value
    });
  };
```

And in your `render` method use the `selectedValue` accordingly:

```
render() {
  return (
    <label>
      color
      <select value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={this.checkLayers}>
        /* {your options} */
      </select>
    </label>
  );
}
```

The next thing to check is the `checkLayers` method. Inside this method you are trying to access `this`. Since the `<select>`'s `onChange` callback is going to be called on a different context as your component (you can check this by logging `this` inside `checkLayers`). As a result of this, you need to bind the `checkLayers` method to your component's context. This can be done by explicitly binding the function when passing it as a callback or by defining the class method as an arrow function.

Binding option (in the `render` method):

```
<select value={selectedValue} onChange={this.checkLayers.bind(this)}>
```

Class method as Arrow function option:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
...
  checkLayers = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      showField: value === "Orange",
      selectedValue: value
    });
  };
...
```

There is also an alternative option using arrow functions:

```
<select value={selectedValue} onChange={(event) => this.checkLayers(event)}>
```

You can learn more about `this`[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

The last thing to check is how you are trying to conditionally render the `<input>` element. Right now you are hardcoding the style as `{ display: 'none' }`. You could change this based on the value of `showField`, but I think is it better only render the `<input>` when `showField` is `true`, like this:

```
  render() {
    const { selectedValue, showField } = this.state;
    return (
      <label>
        color:
        <select value={selectedValue} onChange={this.checkLayers.bind(this)}>
          /* {your options} */
        </select>
        {showField ? (
          <input
            type="text"
            name="project Id"
            id="project Id"
          />
        ) : null}
      </label>
    );
  }
```

Here we are using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to decide if we render the element or we render nothing (using `null`).

You can see the final implementation here:

[image: Edit SO Question - Conditional text field and select]

Comment if you have further questions, cheers!